# Rotate text with CSS/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I have tried this to rotate text to 270 Degree

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

Working Perfectly in Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari working with some spacing issue in IE 8,7,6

but its really Sucks in OPERA Any Idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Using Opera 11 on Linux

Sample: http://www.inwardpath.com.au

```
/* This wrapper is required to rotate the text around the left edge */
#page_title {
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
width: 38px;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-rotation-point: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-rotation-point: 0 0;
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
* html writing-mode: tb-lr;
```

}

Comment: thank you Its working :)  added the 

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`

Working in IE6 also

Comment: I found that ms-writing-mode produced a 'cleaner' font outline than the rotation filter. I was under the impression it was supported in IE6 but I never cared to test it (IE6 must die!)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this ?

```
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is for rotating 90 degrees.  To rotate 270 try this

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
```

Comment: I think you will find that 360 - 90 = 270

Comment: @Kragen Hah lol you are right, I read it too quickly and missed the "-" minus sign

Answer (score 0):

I like using this - http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html