# Rotating an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to rotate an image on a webpage through four orientations at 90 degrees apart. I'd prefer this to happen on the client machines. Can this be done using css? Or will I need to use JavaScript, I need to rotate a background image, a pattern which is repeated on the page.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tada; you can use css3 rotate property as petah said

```
div{
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

& for IE you can use IE filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

**for more check these  links:**

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 works, but my concern would be legacy compatibility.  [According to this matrix](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/), it's not going to work on IE pre version 9.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is an obvious solution, but that's server side so it really doesn't solve your challenge.

I think I'd lean toward [Jquery Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/), which is a very well-done plugin that certainly maintains a simplicity advantage on the presentation layer over a pure CSS solution.  On the basis of compatibility, it's quite a way ahead of pure CSS3 right now.  `<sarcasm>Thanks, Microsoft.</sarcasm>`

Comment: You can rotate elements pre IE9 using ActiveX filters, it's just a pain... http://stackoverflow.com/q/6184589/353278

Comment: @jeff, purely my opinion, but any solution that needs a custom workaround for a specific browser isn't the best path to go down.  Then again, neither is using a 10 year old version of a really poorly thought out browser....

Comment: it would be nice if IE played along, but until then IE will always require custom 'workarounds'. I wouldn't even call this a workaround though.  -moz-transform only works with moz, filter only works with IE. they're both vendor specific.

Comment: not sure about that.....I haven't written an IE hack into a site for at least 2 years.  If you're interested in finding them, there are ways to cope without having to circumvent the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can using CSS3

Check out http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

```
-moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
-o-transform:rotate(120deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(120deg);
transform:rotate(120deg);
```

Comment: Good to know for future reference.  To note though, not supported on IE 8 or lower.